# How to properly remove .AspNet.TwoFactorRememberBrowser cookie after disabling user's 2FA?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity V2.2:
When a user disables 2FA (from having previously been enabled) **the user's cookie `.AspNet.TwoFactorRememberBrowser` remains** and would potentially pose a security risk given the right circumstrances. I'm looking for a clean and appropriate way to remove the cookie for THAT user or should I just be changing the expiration date to something in the past - and if so how would I do that? I've googled a bunch all to no avail as if no one realizes that the cookie remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the absence of a better way, it looks like this will do the trick for Async Function **/Manage/DisableTwoFactorAuthentication**. Note that *isPersistent = True* removes the cookie while *isPersistent = False* just sets the expiration date back.

```
' POST: /Manage/DisableTwoFactorAuthentication
<HttpPost>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Public Async Function DisableTwoFactorAuthentication() As Task(Of ActionResult)
    Await UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), False)
    Dim userInfo = Await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId())
    If userInfo IsNot Nothing Then
        Await SignInManager.SignInAsync(userInfo, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)
        Dim rememberBrowserIdentity = AuthenticationManager.CreateTwoFactorRememberBrowserIdentity(userInfo.Id)
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(New AuthenticationProperties With {
            .IsPersistent = True,   'False still leaves old cookie but with expired date
            .ExpiresUtc = Date.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)
        }, rememberBrowserIdentity)
    End If
    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage")
End Function
```

Hope this helps someone! :-)